# Java 8 ZonedDateTime or OffsetDateTime to replace Joda DateTime

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, jodatime

Before Java8, I used Joda's `DateTime` class to include timezone information and I can easily to convert between `DateTime` and sql `Timestamp`.

Once migrate to Java8, which class I should replace? `OffsetDateTime` or `ZonedDateTime`?

Also, I tried to use `OffsetDateTime`, but it seems can't construct back to `OffsetDateTime` from a sql `Timestamp`.

For Joda `DateTime` and `Timestamp` converter, the code is like:

```
val joda = DateTime.now()
val sqlJoda = new Timestamp(joda.getMillis)
val jodaBack = new DateTime(sqlJoda)
```

But for Java8,

```
val java8 = OffsetDateTime.now()
val sqlJava8 = new Timestamp(java8.toInstant.toEpochMilli)
val java8Back = ???
```

Anyone has some idea about that? It seems Joda `DateTime` is really good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ZonedDateTime`. Here's some sample code I use to convert to `Timestamp` back and forth.

```
public ZonedDateTime from(Timestamp timestamp) {
    if (timestamp == null) {
        return null;
    }
    final ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(timestamp.toInstant(), ZoneId.of("UTC"));
    return zonedDateTime;
}

public Timestamp to(ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime) {
    if (zonedDateTime == null) {
        return null;
    }
    final Timestamp timestamp = Timestamp.valueOf(zonedDateTime.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("UTC")).toLocalDateTime());
    return timestamp;
}
```

Please note that I store date times in the database in UTC.

Comment: The official mapping of a SQL timestamp is either LocalDateTime (timestamp without time zone) or OffsetDateTime (timestamp with timezone). See for example the Maintenance release 2 of JDBC 4 JCP here: https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=221

Comment: Didn't know that. Thanks. Is there any doc out there?

Answer (score 6):

Using the Java 8 API in java.time you could do the following:

```
long ms_since_epoch = 1_500_000_000_000L;
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(ms_since_epoch);

// convert milliseconds in UTC to date
OffsetDateTime dateUTC = OffsetDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

Using your convention:

```
val java8 = OffsetDateTime.now()
val sqlJava8 = new Timestamp(java8.toInstant.toEpochMilli)
val java8Back = OffsetDateTime.ofInstant(sqlJava8.toInstant(), ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

Comment: Which means we assume the database is UTC, right? Thanks.

Comment: Yes. But you can change it to your corresponding time zone using different ZoneId.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that your database type is a `timestamp with time zone`. If it is a `timestamp without timezone` you will need a different type / conversion mechanism.

The [JDBC 4.2 spec](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jdbc-4_2-mrel2-eval-spec/index.html) recommends to map a `timestamp with time zone` to an `OffsetDateTime`. Here is how you can convert between an `OffsetDateTime` and a `java.sql.Timestamp`.

- From `OffsetDateTime` to `Timestamp`:

  ```
  Timestamp ts = ...;
  OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.ofInstant(ts.toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault());
  ```
- From `Timestamp` to `OffsetDateTime`:

  ```
  OffsetDateTime odt = ...;
  Timestamp ts = Timestamp.from(odt.toInstant());
  ```